# how to listen to jsTree deselect event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am trying to listen to deselect event of JsTree like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var jData = [{
        "data": {
            "attr": {
                "title": "A node"               
            },
            "title" : "A node"
            },

            "children": [{
                "data": {
                    "title": "child"
                },
                "children": [{
                    "data": {
                        "title": "Grand Child"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }];

        var myTree = $("#demo1").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "data": jData
            },          
            "plugins": ["json_data", "ui", "themeroller"]
        });

        $(myTree).bind("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data) {
            console.log("selected!");
        });
        $(myTree).bind("deselect_node.jstree", function(evt, data) {
            console.log("deselected!");
        });

    });
```

According to the documentation [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/ui), 'deselect_node' triggers an event, but nothing seems to happen when I do like above. I am able to listen to select event though.

How to listen to jsTree deselect event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me, perhaps the missing semi-colon is breaking in some browsers.

Here is re-write of your example as a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fyDE6/

Updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fyDE6/2/

Comment: Hold ctrl+(mouse click) to deselect

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but we can't tell the users to press 'ctrl' while clicking on nodes

Comment: Moreover I want the deselect event to be fired for this node when the use selects some other node, not when the user clicks on the same node.

Comment: you can change ctrl to any other key or set the "ui": {"select_multiple_modifier": "ctrl"} setting to "on" to always allow multi-select and deselect on every click. See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fyDE6/1/

Comment: Thanks, as I was mentioning earlier I want the deselect event to be fired for the currently selected node when I click(or select) on some other node...not when I click again on the same node...

Comment: Lets try this one more time: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fyDE6/2/ This example deselects all except the currently clicked node on event select_node. It will trigger deselect_node event for the previously selected nodes.

Comment: That was great! Thanks...that is how I think jsTree should have worked in first place...I updated the link to jsFiddle, the solution would help many others like me...thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. I agree, it should have work like this in the first place and not needed a workaround. I filed a bug on jstree's github: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/247 I'll update the post once I hear a response.