# Deselect selected treenode JStree - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jstree

**Situation**

When my page is loaded and my treeview is visible, no treenode is selected.
When I click on a node, it's selected, which is default behavior.

**Question**

How can I deselect the node while clicking on the same node? So I want to click on a selected node to deselect it. I have been searching into the documentation. But the event 'select_node' will first select the node before I can check for it's selectstatus.

I know there is a way to deselect a node with code when I click on a button but that's not what I want. I want to click the already selected node.

How can I do this?

**Link(s)**

Documentation events JStree: http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=enable_node.jstree

Comment: do you want this selected/deselected status to be saved to the server side? So that the next time you load the tree again, you get the same state back, where you left off from??

Comment: No I just don't want to select a node when I click outside the tree.

Comment: There are some good suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576444/how-to-listen-to-jstree-deselect-event/ . You should keep press CTRL for deselect.

Answer (score 11):

This issue popped up for me today. I expected at least a configuration option that could be set when initializing the tree. While it's not pretty, this is what I did to circumvent the issue:

```
var _selectedNodeId;
$("#myTree").on("select_node.jstree", function (e, _data) {
    if ( _selectedNodeId === _data.node.id ) {
        _data.instance.deselect_node(_data.node);
        _selectedNodeId = "";
    } else {
        _selectedNodeId = _data.node.id;
    }
}).jstree();
```

Essentially, I am tracking the selected node and checking this against the node that has been clicked. The downside of this method is that if you have a callback firing on "changed.jstree" it will fire twice, since you are "selecting" first and then "deselecting" if it's already selected.

Comment: _data.instance.deselect_node(_data.node); <-- This was the magical line of code I've been searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to enable this behavior via adding `multiselect` plugin. And set `multiple` configuration option to `false` when you want single select:

```
$('#my-tree').jstree({
  core: { multiple: false },
  plugins: ['multiselect']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To deselect selected node on click.

```
$('#my-tree').('click', '.jstree-clicked', function () {
  $('#my-tree').(true).deselect_node(this);
});
```

Also you can add a listener on deselect.

```
$("#myTree").on("deselect_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a proper way to unselect all nodes:

```
$("#jstree").jstree().uncheck_all(true);
```